# Pattern searching in array of words

Tags: search, tree, pattern-matching

I need to search in big array of words using pattern. Pattern can contain sequences of letters and wildcard * which can represents every letter(or some of them). Pattern represents the whole word or words. I found that I an use Suffix tree. But I need effective way to store this tree on disk because it's need lots of RAM. Is there any effective ways to search through the list of words which is stored on the drive? It also should be an online algorithm (I mean that I can append new words to tree)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try aho-corasick algorithm. It's the fastest multi pattern search algorithm. You can also use a wildcard. You can try my implementation in PHP @ https://phpahocorasick.codeplex.com.